# Quickly put all data from an SQL query into an array with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

I'm using something like the following PHP code to put all data from a query into an array:

```
<?php

$results = array();

$q = odbc_exec("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($q)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

?>
```

This works fine, but it is very slow when the query contains thousands of rows.

My question is, is there any way in PHP to dump all the data into an array without having to loop through each record one by one?

NOTE: Using MS SQL Server for the database.

Comment: When you have to read a lot of data, it will always need some time. Do you really need ever single row of that table? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can do stuff inside the `while` loop itself, if you don't need to rely on the array any further.

Comment: I was hoping there was a function to put the entire query contents into an array with out using the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the `cursor_type` in `odbc_connect` made odbc fetching much quicker.

```
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)
```

http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2007/08/02/odbc-for-udb-and-php-how-i-increased-performance-by-400/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using mssql functions instead of odbc, but its unlikely to make a large difference.

With the way drivers work, the result set is an iterator handle to the result data itself. In some cases, php doesn't actually get the data until the row is requested by php. Unless there is a fetch all available in the driver, looping through all the rows is generally your only option.

If you don't need all the columns, you could limit the data being transfered by specifing only the columns you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to do this with ADOdb (a database abstraction library for PHP) using the `GetAll()` function:

http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

> $results = $DB->GetAll("SELECT * FROM table");

This returns all the rows as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: According to their website...Installing the ADOdb C extension will speed up GetAll() and GetArray() by 100% (http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#extension). Without using the C extension it seemed just slightly quicker then standard PHP code.

Comment: It might be that even with the extension, you wouldn't notice much difference. Dunno. Would be interesting to find out if there is any noticable benefit - I'm a bit skeptical that there would be.